# Check the convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3(n^2+11)}{n^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m trying to check the convergence of this series but I don't know how to start.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3(n^2+11)}{n^4}$$
I thought about using Comparison test. so I know when I have some $\theta$ any trigonometric function I will take some $b_n$ as another series, so I choose $\frac{1}{n^2+11}$
I would like to get some advice how to do that, Thanks!

Comment: HINT: $$\frac{\sin^3(n^2+11)}{n^4}<\frac1{n^4}$$

Comment: Show it converges absolutely.

Comment: Try to compare with a convergence series such as 1/n^4

Comment: @labbhattacharjee its enough? I did it at first, I know that harmonic series if p ( power ) is $>1$ so its converges

Comment: @OfirAttia, http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Absolutely_Convergent_Series_is_Convergent#Proof_for_Real_Numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that 
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R},\quad |\sin(x)| \le 1$$
then
$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\quad \left|\frac{\sin^3(n^2+11)}{n^4} \right|\le \frac{1}{n^4} $$
and we know that $\sum \frac{1}{n^4}$ converge and the absolute convergence implies the convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\left|\frac{\sin^3(n^2+11)}{n^4} \right|\le \left|\frac{1}{n^4} \right|\le \frac {1}{n^2}$. By comparison criterion, the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ implies the convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3(n^2+11)}{n^4}.$$

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer: care to elaborate on this act?