# Check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2n+5)}{n^{11/9}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to check the convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2n+5)}{n^{11/9}}$$
my questions is if I can change $\cos(2n+5)$ to $(-1)^n$?

Then if I have trigonometric function( $\cos,\sin$ ) I can change it to $(-1)^n$ because its between $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Exactly the same kind of proof as in your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451889/check-the-convergence-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin3n211n4 leads to the convergence of your series

Comment: becuase the other question is marked already so I asked it on new question, I was wondering if you could make this thing. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. You’ve no reason to think that $\cos(2n+5)$ behaves like $(-1)^n$, and indeed it does not. You can, however, use the fact that $|\cos u|\le 1$ for all $u$ to test for *absolute* convergence by observing that

$$\left|\frac{\cos(2n+5)}{n^{11/9}}\right|\le\frac1{n^{11/9}}\;.$$

And absolute convergence certainly gives you the desired convergence.

Comment: just wonder if its right to change it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use this fat that: $$|u_n|\le\frac{1}{n^{11/9}}$$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Thanks Dr. :-)

Comment: Nice hint, indeed ;-) +1